# How can I read multiple text files and extract data with some conditions, then add columns based on another lookup table in python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am a beginner of python and Im trying to use python to open multiple text files (5g data in total), and only select lines with c = "string111" condition, and then try to add another column based on the lookup table (csv file), then write an cvs or excel file in the end.

for example: the files look like:

```
a b c d 
string1 string11 string111 678
string2 string22 string222 890
string3 string33 string333 2739
```

I have another lookup csv file:

```
a b c e
string1 string11 string111 string1111
string2 string22 string222 string2222
string3 string33 string333 string1111
```

In the end, I want to get csv file like:

```
e d
string1111 98032 (this is aggregate data)
string2222 677...
```

Since the data is too large, it's hard to use excel to process it. Just wanted to know the python code to resolve this simple question.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Excel is perfectly able to process this. With Excel 2010 and 2013 you can use the free Power Query Add-in, and in Excel 2016 it is called Get & Transform on the Data ribbon.

Create a query for the lookup CSV and load it as a connection only.

Then create a query for one of the CSV files, apply the filter, then merge with the lookup CSV and perform any other operation you want to do.

The result can be loaded into a worksheet and saved as a CSV.

The above can be done by just clicking ribbon icons, and the resulting scripts in the Power Query language "M" can be modified in the Advanced Editor.